# Reading Rdata file with different encoding

Tags: r, linux, encoding, utf-8, rdata

I have an .RData file to read on my Linux (UTF-8) machine, but I know the file is in Latin1 because I've created them myself on Windows. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the original files or a Windows machine and I need to read those files on my Linux machine.

To read an Rdata file, the normal procedure is to run `load("file.Rdata")`. Functions such as `read.csv` have an `encoding` argument that you can use to solve those kind of issues, but `load` has no such thing. If I try `load("file.Rdata", encoding = latin1)`, I just get this (expected) error:

> Error in load("file.Rdata", encoding = "latin1") : 
>     unused argument (encoding = "latin1")

What else can I do? My files are loaded with text variables containing accents that get corrupted when opened in an UTF-8 environment.

Comment: RData files do not have encodings. You need to load the serialized Rdata and then re-encode the values once they are inside the R workspace. If this remains unclear after reading `?Encoding`, then do the load and post the output of `dput(head(object))`.

Comment: @42, this seems to solve the problem, too bad apparently I need to apply `Encoding(x)` to each vector in my dataframe. I'll take a better look at it and will get back to you.

Comment: You can record the names in the workspace before and after the load and then work on the difference for the items that have character values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to 42's comment, I've managed to write a function to recode the file:

```
fix.encoding <- function(df, originalEncoding = "latin1") {
  numCols <- ncol(df)
  for (col in 1:numCols) Encoding(df[, col]) <- originalEncoding
  return(df)
}
```

The meat here is the command `Encoding(df[, col]) <- "latin1"`, which takes column `col` of dataframe `df` and converts it to latin1 format. Unfortunately, `Encoding` only takes column objects as input, so I had to create a function to sweep all columns of a dataframe object and apply the transformation.

Of course, if your problem is in just a couple of columns, you're better off just applying the `Encoding` to those columns instead of the whole dataframe (you can modify the function above to take a set of columns as input). Also, if you're facing the inverse problem, i.e. reading an R object created in Linux or Mac OS into Windows, you should use `originalEncoding = "UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 3):

following up on previous answers, this is a minor update which makes it work on factors and dplyr's tibble. Thanks for inspiration.

```
fix.encoding <- function(df, originalEncoding = "UTF-8") {
numCols <- ncol(df)
df <- data.frame(df)
for (col in 1:numCols)
{
        if(class(df[, col]) == "character"){
                Encoding(df[, col]) <- originalEncoding
        }

        if(class(df[, col]) == "factor"){
                        Encoding(levels(df[, col])) <- originalEncoding
}
}
return(as_data_frame(df))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this. I took the liberty to modify your function in case you have a dataframe with some columns as character and some as non-character. Otherwise, an error occurs:

```
> fix.encoding(adress)
Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "latin1") :
 a character vector argument expected
```

So here is the modified function:

```
fix.encoding <- function(df, originalEncoding = "latin1") {
    numCols <- ncol(df)
    for (col in 1:numCols)
            if(class(df[, col]) == "character"){
                    Encoding(df[, col]) <- originalEncoding
            }
    return(df)
}
```

However, this will not change the encoding of level's names in a "factor" column. Luckily, I found this to change all factors in your dataframe to character (which may be not the best approach, but in my case that's what I needed):

```
i <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.character)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using dplyr's `mutate_if`:

```
fix_encoding <- function(x) {
  Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
  return(x)
}
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character,fix_encoding)
```

And for factor variables that have to be recoded:

```
fix_encoding_factor <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
  x <- as.factor(x)
  return(x)
}
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,fix_encoding_factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be a problem on Windows with files created in older versions of R (<4.2).
To avoid this, I use the following code to specify the encoding and save them again (no reprocessing would be needed):

```
file <- "file.RData"
df.encoding <- "latin1"

# Load data.frame
df.name <- load(file) 
df <- get(df.name[1])

# Names
Encoding(names(df)) <- df.encoding

# Variable labels (if present)
if (!is.null(vlabels <- attr(df, "variable.labels"))) {
  Encoding(vlabels) <- df.encoding  
  Encoding(names(vlabels)) <- df.encoding
  attr(df, "variable.labels") <- vlabels  
}

# Character variables
vchar <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[vchar] <- lapply(df[vchar],  function(x) {
  Encoding(x) <- df.encoding
  x
})

# Factors
vcat <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[vcat] <- lapply(df[vcat],  function(x) {
  Encoding(levels(x)) <- df.encoding
  x
})

# Save
assign(df.name[1], df)
save(list = df.name[1], file = file)
```