# R Script not able to read .Rda file when executed from Java

Tags: java, r, maven, scriptengine, renjin

I'm new to `Rscript` so please bear with me, I need to execute a R script (written by another developer) from java  and for that I'm using `Renjin`. The R script file and other required files are on `classpath` i.e. under resources folder.

To achieve this I'm loading `Rscript` from classpath and it gets loaded successfully, and `Rscript` tries to load a `abc.Rda` file internally which is also present in classpath (parallel to R script), the code for same is below

```
load('abc.Rda')
```

But when I try to execute script then it throws exception as below:

> Could not read from "file:///D:/data/{project-dir}/abc.Rda" because it is a not a file.

Please suggest where I'm making mistake.

Comment: Did you try to give absolute file path to function?

Comment: Yup tried that, but the problem is same

Comment: I've tried various tests but wasn't able to produce any errors: single, double quotes, capitalized file extension when actual is lower case, etc.  
    `save(d, file='abc.rda')`   `load('abc.Rda')`

Comment: Could you try `load('abc.Rda', verbose = TRUE)` to see if it gives any more clues?

Also, maybe you could look into character encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024654/reading-rdata-file-with-different-encoding

Comment: What's in the Rda file? Could this be related to or a regression of https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/106? (I'm assuming that the R code works without error if run outside of renjin.)

Comment: It certainly appears that `{project-dir}` is not being expanded properly. Since R has no notion of a "project" this is likely due to some IDE that is not behaving as expected. RStudio perhaps?

Comment: I've tried executing R script by providing fully classified path name but the error was same.

Comment: As far as I know Renjine doesn't implent all R functionalities (at least the version I used one year and half ago) so maybe the R code inside the rda file can't be executed (although the error refers to the file path)

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible R script in the open question..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why using the absolute path didn't work: perhaps the script is incorrectly calling `setwd(dir='/bad/{project-dir}')` somewhere earlier?

Renjin actually mediates file system operations through [Apache Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) (VFS). So if you specifically want a resource on the classpath, you can use the "res:" protocol, for example:

```
load('res:com/acme/mypackage/abc.Rda')
```

This should work whether the file is actually on the filesystem or packaged as part of a jar or other archive.