# Encoding problem when reading .Rdata-data

Tags: r, dataframe, encoding, dplyr, iso-8859-1

So I have some data in a `.Rdata`-file. In this file there is a dataframe I'd like to use. It's called `d`. What I did to read it is the following:

```
> env = environment()
> load("data/Erfurt_rent_new.Rdata", envir = env)
> df = env$d
```

Then I wanted to access a column by typing `df$...`, but it immediately prompts me with:

`Error in tolower(completions) : invalid multibyte string 6`

I then tried to change the encoding od the columns. There are some german names in it and I thought this might be the problem. So I tried (as described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024654/reading-rdata-file-with-different-encoding))

```
fix.encoding <- function(df, originalEncoding = "latin1") {
  numCols <- ncol(df)
  for (col in 1:numCols) Encoding(df[, col]) <- originalEncoding
  return(df)
}
```

But when I run it it says:

```
Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = originalEncoding) : 
  a character vector argument expected
```

I then tried to change the default behaviour of `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` to `FALSE` by:

`df1 = data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

but then it says:

`Error in make.names(vnames, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 6`

So I'm a little lost. And all I'd like to do is read in my data;)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4303162) to your question. Without having data that reproduces your problem, it is impossible to know for certain what is going wrong.